# Random Numbers and programming logic

Tags: c++, random, srand

I'm having trouble with the assignment below.

"Write a program that generates a random integer between 1-100 and then asks the user to guess what the number is. If the user's guess is higher than the random number, the program should display “Too high, try again.” If the user’s guess is lower than the random number, the program should display “Too low, try again.” The program should use a loop that repeats until the user correctly guesses the random number."

How do I make the random numbers work, and is there a better/more efficient way to write any parts? I'm still learning C++

Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // declare variables
    int rightAnswer, userAnswer;

    // determine rightAnswer
    srand (time(NULL));
    rightAnswer = (rand() % 100) + 1;

    // begin the game
    cout << "I'm thinking of a number between 1-100!" << endl;
    do{
        // collect data
        cout << "Guess: ";
        cin >> userAnswer;

        // if else statements to determine correctness
        if (userAnswer < 1 || userAnswer > 100)
            cout << "The number is in the range 1-100. Try again!" << endl;
        else if (userAnswer > rightAnswer)
            cout << "Too high! Try again!" << endl;
        else if (userAnswer < rightAnswer)
            cout << "Too low! Try again!" << endl;
        else
            cout << "That's it! Good job!" << endl << ":)";


    } while (userAnswer != rightAnswer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are hoping SO will give you.  The code looks functional at first look.  Where is it breaking?

Comment: This looks good enough except that the random number is not choosen uniformly in the given range. Do you see any problem.

Comment: Your program is working correctly on my system.

Comment: It's working? Mine displays a huge page of error stuff, not sure what to call it. I forgot to mention I program with a Mac and Xcode, would that effect it?

Comment: When you say it works, you mean exactly as the problem describes?

Answer (score 7):

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) you can generate random number more uniformly in given range using correct choice of [Random number distributions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). One example of uniform distribution usage is shown below:

```
#include <random>

...
std::random_device rd; // obtain a random number
std::mt19937 engine(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribution(1, 100); // define the range

const int rightanswer = distribution(engine);
```

Comment: Is there a way to use it without engines? I'm pretty sure we're supposed to use the rand and srand. I'm just having trouble seeing how they work in general

Comment: The best I can suggest for your purpose with rand is is: `do {rightAnswer = rand() % 128;}while(rightAnswer >= 100)++rightAnswer;`. If you are allowed to use modern `C++`, prefer the method suggested in answer.

Comment: why set rightAnswer to be above the range, and why % 28? and also why ++rightAnswer

Comment: Because if the modulo (100 in your case and 128 in my case) is not power of 2, you would get a non-uniform distribution. The example in comment generates a number uniformly (assuming rand generates uniform) in range [0, 127] and ignore if it is larger than 99. Then it transforms [0-99] to [1-100] by adding . Please watch [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDPMpc-ENqY) to understand why `rand` is harmful.